# Cannot launch python winpexpect library

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, pexpect

i try to use winpexpect on windows 7 64bits with python 2.6.

```
>>> import winpexpect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.6-py2.6.egg\winpexpect.py", l
ine 11, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <mo
dule>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 98, in __im
port_pywin32_system_module__
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes26.dll)
```

Or the installation doesn't raise any error:

```
Extracting winpexpect-1.6-py2.6.egg to c:\python26\lib\site-packages
winpexpect 1.6 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed c:\python26\lib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.6-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for winpexpect==1.6
Searching for pywin32==218
Best match: pywin32 218
Adding pywin32 218 to easy-install.pth file   
Using c:\python26\lib\site-packages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`winpexpect` depends on [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). You can find install files [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/).

[Use this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/pywin32-218.win-amd64-py2.6.exe/download) to download the recent version for your system. (Python 2.6 64bit version)